# How to open and then copy/paste data from multiple excel files with similar names?

Tags: vba, loops, copy-paste

I want to perform analysis of a list of similarly named files. For example, at a specific directory, call it "\USSECVAPFL23\23AM0039\A\" there will be folder with a list of 15-30 files. The names of these files are all similar except for different policy numbers. For example one name might be "Policy 0048284.xlsx" then "Policy 3329851.xlsx" then "Policy 323483.xlsx" etc. My goal is to one by one open each file, copy a range of cells, and paste them into a new workbook. Then save that new workbook as "Results 0048284" before moving onto the next file and doing the same thing until all the files in the folder have a "Results" file. Is this possible?

This was my attempt at looping and opening each file but it doesn't open the files.

```
Sub openfiles()
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As 
Integer, j As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "\\USSECVAPFL23\23AM0039\A\ACTL\Tax Actuarial\Product Tax\Calculators\TC 
Calculator\Audit 7702\CUNA CVAT Test"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xlsx")
    Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    fileName = Dir()
    Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your looping over the files looks correct. Now start to code the other part to transfer the data to a new WB and we will be happy to help you as soon as you face any specific problem.